# Do T-cells express MHC molecules?

Tags: immunology, mhc

T-cells recognize the MHC molecules and body's own peptides. When it doesn't, it alarms the immune system. But do T-cells express MHC molecules ? If so, how are they using it? If not, what happens when a virus infects T-cells? (Yes, I am confused about HIV infection mechanism too. [They escape from immune response by altering their genes and disrupting the MHC-peptide bonding](http://www.mcb.uct.ac.za/cann/335/McMichael/McMichael.html). I can see that this can work in macrophages. But what is the situation in T-cells ?)

Comment: They express MHC1.

Comment: They do not express MHC II molecules.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that T-cells do not express MHC class II molecules. Please see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15120183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of MHC molecules:

**All nucleated cells express MHC class 1 proteins**.  A sample of all proteins produced within the cell are 'sliced' into their constituents which are then presented by MHC-I receptors.  This means that if a virus infects a cell, the foreign proteins the cell is induced to make are expressed on the cell membrane by MHC-I.  This is important as antibodies can not cross cell membranes, therefore this is the method by which a cell signals that it is infected by a virus.

MHC II are the special molecules that are only expressed in antigen-presenting cells, which I think is what you are referring to.  As neither CD4 or CD8 T-cells present antigens, they do not express MHC-II themselves.  Instead CD4 have receptors for MHCII  (while CD8 have receptors for MHCI), allowing them to interact with antigens presented by other immune cells.

If a virus infects T-cells, the viral proteins are sampled by the MHC-I pathway and presented via MHC-I on the surface of the infected T-Cell.  The immune response then progresses as for any other virally infected cell, destruction by CD8 T-Killers that destroy the cell by non-phagocytic means.

Comment: Are you positive CD4 cells don't present antigens? I could have sworn they had the capability to.

Comment: @MCM that was off the top of my head, I'll have a read of my notes tomorrow.  Happy New Year!

Comment: Are antigen-presenting cells a specific type of cells? I've always been confused about this because the label seems so general.

Comment: @shigeta I would say they're a *class* of cell, defined by their expression of MHC-II.

Comment: I would expect that they do something else besides only presenting antigen - is that their only function?

Comment: Antigen-presenting cells include dendritic cells, and B-cells, but there are more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigen_presenting_cells

Comment: "All nucleated cells express MHC class 1 proteins." - This is a pretty bold statement... :D At least I would add "human cells"...

Comment: I believe this is the better answer, though I recall this being a debated issue. Some MHC class II molecules are found on at least some subtypes of T cells, though it is (at least was) unclear whether they acquire them through expression or from other cells.
http://www.jleukbio.org/content/63/6/707,
http://www.bloodjournal.org/content/101/7/2704,
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7522009,
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1074761305003006