# Why do T cells have MHC II receptors?

Tags: immunology, antibody, antigen

I have seen the answer to this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/do-t-cells-express-mhc-molecules) which says that T cells do not express MHC II proteins which would make sense.

However, my textbook "The immune system" by Peter Parham disagrees. It says that T cells do gain MHC II receptors after activation.

[image]

> *Activated T cells express MHC class II molecules, whereas resting T cells do not.

I cannot see why this is needed. MHC II molecules are for CD4 cells (helper T cells).

If the T cell presenting the antigen was a CD4 cell, then that seems useless, because this cell was already the one that could recognise this particular antigen - so why show it to others? The chance that another T cell that could recognise it too would be incredibly small no?

I guess I can see the merit of a CD8 T killer cell to show the antigen, as it could alert other CD4 T cells to come assist (although cytokines seem like a better method...)

So what is the purpose of T cells, in particular CD4, of showing MHC II proteins?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

That's the description in my book which has the same image.
The book is: Janeway's Immunology (9th Edition)

Article discussing MHC Class II expression in humans:
https://doi.org/10.4049/jimmunol.168.2.763

Excerpt from the book:

> The processing and presentation of pathogen-derived antigens has two
> distinct purposes: inducing the development of armed effector T cells,
> and triggering the effector functions of these armed cells at sites of
> infection. MHC class I molecules bind peptides that are recognized by
> CD8 T cells, and MHC class II molecules bind peptides that are
> recognized by CD4 T cells, a pattern of recognition determined by
> specific binding of the CD8 or CD4 molecules to the respective MHC
> molecules (see Section 4-18). The importance of this specificity of
> recognition lies in the different distributions of MHC class I and
> class II molecules on cells throughout the body. Nearly all somatic
> cells (except red blood cells) express MHC class I molecules.
> Consequently, the CD8 T cell is primarily responsible for pathogen
> surveillance and cytolysis of somatic cells. Also called cytotoxic T
> cells, their function is to kill the cells they recognize. CD8 T cells
> are therefore an important mechanism in eliminating sources of new
> viral particles and bacteria that live only in the cytosol, and thus
> freeing the host from infection.
>
> By contrast, MHC class II molecules
> are expressed primarily only on cells of the immune system, and
> particularly by dendritic cells, macrophages, and B cells. Thymic
> cortical epithelial cells and activated, but not naive, T cells can
> express MHC class II molecules, which can also be induced on many
> cells in response to the cytokine IFN-γ. Thus, CD4 T cells can
> recognize their cognate antigens during their development in the
> thymus, on a limited set of ‘professional’ antigen-presenting cells,
> and on other somatic cells under specific inflammatory conditions.
> Effector CD4 T cells comprise several subsets with different
> activities that help eliminate the pathogens. Importantly, naive CD8
> and CD4 T cells can become armed effector cells only after
> encountering their cognate antigen once it has been processed and
> presented by activated dendritic cells.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the most recent [review](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15120183/) specialized on this topic (I found) dates back to 2004, and it's pretty confusingly written, IMHO. The general gist of it appears to be that T cells can act as APC cells under some conditions (aka T-APC) and it was generally thought that this serves a down-regulatory function for T cells, e.g.

> There is considerable evidence, dating as far back as
> 1978, in support of the notion that human activated
> T cells can function as APC (so-called T-APC) and
> thereby affect the activities of other T cells. [...]
>
> Most reports show that MHC class II–mediated antigen
> presentation by T-APCs provides downregulatory signals
> by inducing either apoptosis or clonal anergy in activated
> T cells or cytotoxicity in resting T cells.
> This T-T presentation-induced anergy does not appear to
> result from TCR ligation in the absence of costimulatory
> molecules, because activated T cells themselves express
> CD80 or CD86.

More recent work has found that [trogocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trogocytosis) is possible between T cells, i.e. they can pass each other peptide-bound MHC. In particular trogocytosis [explains](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3575485/#s2title) some mysteries in this area, such as how mouse CD8 T cells, which cannot express the MHC-II gene, themselves actually acquire such receptors on their surface.

One such recent [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211124721001753) proposes that such T-T interactions differentiate CD4 T cells into regulatory ones vs [Th17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_helper_17_cell) pro-inflammatory ones:

> We investigate the functional outcome of T-T cell antigen presentation by CD4 T cells and find that the antigen-presenting T cells (Tpres) predominantly differentiate into regulatory T cells (Treg), whereas T cells that have been stimulated by Tpres cells predominantly differentiate into Th17 pro-inflammatory cells.
>
> [image]

The introductory section of this 2021 paper contains a useful minireview of the directions of research  (some of them being apparently somewhat contradictory to each other, if more specific conditions of the experiments aren't taken into account)

> Another important mechanism of intercellular communication within the immune system is trogocytosis (Joly and Hudrisier, 2003), where T cells and natural killer (NK) cells acquire micrometer-sized fragments of the APC membrane (Carlin et al., 2001; Vanherberghen et al., 2004). These fragments can contain immune-modulating membrane receptors such as killer inhibitory receptors and major histocompatibility complex (MHC) class I and II complexes. Previously it was shown that MHC-II vesicles are released by APCs and acquired by responding T cells (Arnold and Mannie, 1999; Patel et al., 1999). T cells also acquire peptide MHC (pMHC) complexes at the IS [immunological synapse] via a process that requires T cell receptor (TCR) internalization and TCR signaling (Huang et al., 1999; Hudrisier et al., 2001). In addition, they acquire CD80 and CD86, ligands of the co-stimulatory receptor CD28 (Hwang et al., 2000; Sabzevari et al., 2001). This could convert T cells into APCs. Both CD8 T cell-dendritic cell (DC) interactions and secondary T cell-T cell interactions are required to generate protective CD8 T cells (Gérard et al., 2013), and CD8 recall responses depend on CD8 T cells taking up MHC-II from DCs to present it to CD4 T cells and obtain their help (Romagnoli et al., 2013). In contrast, other results have suggested that pMHC acquisition by T cells may play an inhibitory role (Dhainaut and Moser, 2014). For instance, T cell antigen presentation to other T cells has been associated with the induction of anergy, apoptosis, and even tolerance (Chai et al., 1998; Mannie et al., 1996), and may represent a mechanism to limit clonal expansion (Tsang et al., 2003).

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the article you provided it is stated that the function of MHC class II molecules on activated CD4+ T cells is still unclear. It is believed that these MHC class II molecules-presenting T cells have potential ability to act as antigen presenting cells and induce immune response by activating other T cells. They are also capable of inducing down-regulatory signals for immune response by inducing anergy in activated T cells and cytotoxic resting T cells. In addition, they have also been reported to transduce intracellular signals into T lymphocytes.